# ./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb

This error displays while opening mongod:

```
adel@Xubuntu-pc:~/mongo/bin$ ./mongod --dbpath ~/mongo-data/
./mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared  object 
    file: No such file or directory
adel@Xubuntu-pc:~/mongo/bin$
```

(From [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xrX2.png).)

**Note that** `libcurl.so.4` is found in anaconda dir. */home/adel/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.so.4*

Hmm, any solution!

Comment: What are your specific versions of MongoDB & Ubuntu? How did you install MongoDB?

Comment: My OS is Xubuntu 18.04 & I downloaded  Ubuntu 16.04 version from  MongoDB website, bec. I didn't found version to my OS. @Stennie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MongoDB 4.0.0 packages for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) are not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic). In particular, the `libcurl3` and `libcurl4` packages on Ubuntu 18.04 [both provide `libcurl.so.4`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/1754294) (with conflicting APIs).

As per [SERVER-33000](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33000) in the MongoDB issue tracker, an Ubuntu 18.04 package will be included with the upcoming MongoDB 4.0.1 release.

If you want to use MongoDB 4.0.0 in the interim for a development environment, a workaround would be to install the generic [Linux 64-bit legacy](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community) binary download. The generic download does not include TLS/SSL or other features requiring external library dependencies (such as `libcurl`). This approach will also require you to set up your own service definition for MongoDB, so is best suited for a development environment.

Alternatively, you should be able to install the latest MongoDB 3.6 community server package, which does not have the `libcurl` dependency that is problematic on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl4
```

Worked for me for Ubuntu 18.04